# How to make sure spark job is Utilizing all the available resource (utilizing all the containers)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I have a spark streaming job that reads data from kafka and puts into a Datawarehouse.

It is running perfectly fine but point of concerns is when I monitored the logs, I noticed that logs from my application only on one container and rest of the container only showing GC (Allocation Failure). Have tried with different combination of -num-executors and --executor-memory.
Is it really utilizing total available resources of the cluster or only one worker node is doing all the job.

I am using AWS EMR to deploy my job. cluster has one master(m5xLarge) and 2 datanode(m5xLarge).
memory available in on each node 16 gb, 4 vcpu.

Logs from one of the container

```
2021-03-25T17:30:30.539+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:30.539+0000: [ParNew: 73307K->6385K(74944K), 0.0072151 secs] 161323K->95020K(241536K), 0.0073002 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:31.249+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:31.249+0000: [ParNew: 73009K->4636K(74944K), 0.0065039 secs] 161644K->94637K(241536K), 0.0065701 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:31.457+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:31.457+0000: [ParNew: 71260K->3970K(74944K), 0.0040602 secs] 161261K->93971K(241536K), 0.0041415 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:31.700+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:31.700+0000: [ParNew: 70594K->5094K(74944K), 0.0044768 secs] 160595K->95095K(241536K), 0.0045439 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:33.044+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:33.044+0000: [ParNew: 71718K->7049K(74944K), 0.0131990 secs] 161719K->97050K(241536K), 0.0132825 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:35.042+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:35.042+0000: [ParNew: 73673K->7211K(74944K), 0.0063486 secs] 163674K->97868K(241536K), 0.0064325 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:35.202+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:35.202+0000: [ParNew: 73835K->8320K(74944K), 0.0125162 secs] 164492K->103499K(241536K), 0.0125880 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:35.340+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:35.340+0000: [ParNew: 74904K->8320K(74944K), 0.0165272 secs] 170084K->116030K(241536K), 0.0166063 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:37.309+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:37.309+0000: [ParNew: 74944K->8319K(74944K), 0.0116421 secs] 182654K->117918K(241536K), 0.0117176 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:37.441+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:37.441+0000: [ParNew: 74943K->6171K(74944K), 0.0188051 secs] 184542K->120606K(241536K), 0.0188938 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2021-03-25T17:30:37.652+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-03-25T17:30:37.652+0000: [ParNew: 72674K->8320K(74944K), 0.0080351 secs] 187109K->124677K(241536K), 0.0081014 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

Spark version 2.4.0
Scala Version 2.11.12

Thanks

Comment: How many partitions does your Kafka topic has? If it has only one, only one executor can read from that topic and all the other will be idle.

Comment: Kafka has only one partition, so does it mean that, there is no point in adding multiple worker node (data node) ?  And can we consider in case of Kafka as a source number of partitions= number of executers?

Comment: Is there anything we can do to make sure that it can utilize the available resources? If creating partition at the source ( Kafka) is not an option?

Comment: Yes, unless you can increase the partitions in the topic it does not make sense to add more workers to the same application. There is nothing you can do otherwise. Imagine you have 3 workers reading all from the same one partition. How could they which message has already consumed by another worker to avoid consuming duplicates?

Comment: will repartition help in spark side? just after I read from kafka?

Comment: I'll try to give you more details around it, currently I have subscribed to multiple topics and each topic requires different logic to process.
So on masterdataframe( the one I get after reading from kafka) if I can create partition based on the topic will it help in parallelizing the process?

Comment: @mike I have created partition in kafka but still it is utilizing only one container, anything I can check ?